# Combining border-top,border-right,border-left,border-bottom in CSS

Tags: css, border

Is there a way of combining border-top,border-right,border-left,border-bottom in CSS like a super shorthand style.

eg:

```
border: (1px solid #ff0) (2px dashed #f0F) (3px dotted #F00) (5px solid #09f);
```

Answer (score 212, accepted):

No, you cannot set them all in a single statement.
At the general case, you need at least three properties:

```css
border-color: red green white blue;
border-style: solid dashed dotted solid;
border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
```

However, that would be quite messy. It would be more readable and maintainable with four:

```css
border-top:    1px solid  #ff0;
border-right:  2px dashed #f0F;
border-bottom: 3px dotted #f00;
border-left:   5px solid  #09f;
```

Comment: This works really nice when you are trying to show a border on just the top and bottom: border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 0;

Comment: You might want to add the semi-colons in your second snippet.

Comment: is there any way to combine all in one line??

Answer (score 30):

Your case is an extreme one, but here is a solution for others that fits a more common scenario of wanting to style fewer than 4 borders exactly the same.

```
border: 1px dashed red; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
```

that is a little shorter, and maybe easier to read than

```
border-top: 1px dashed red;  border-right: 1px dashed red; border-left: 1px dashed red;
```

or

```
border-color: red; border-style: dashed; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
```

Comment: Your first line of code is the better option I think and it saves many bytes, especially in large CSS files with lots of bordering.

Comment: If you have large CSS files, another option to consider is using a CSS preprocessor or PHP to preprocess the CSS. This permits more logical and more compact CSS.

Answer (score 17):

I can relate to the problem, there should be a shorthand like...

```
border: 1px solid red top bottom left;
```

Of course that doesn't work! Kobi's answer gave me an idea. Let's say you want to do top, bottom and left, but not right. Instead of doing border-top: border-left: border-bottom: (three statements) you could do two like this, the zero cancels out the right side.

```
border: 1px dashed yellow;
border-width:1px 0 1px 1px;
```

Two statements instead of three, small improvement :-D

Comment: isn't this the same answer as the one by @DG. from 2013?

Answer (score -3):

No you can't set them as single one 
for example if you have 
    div{
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    }
same properties for all fours then you can set them in single line

```
div{border:2px solid red;}
```

Comment: Dont you think, your point is already answered by other answers?